# How to save times to external file as3

Tags: actionscript-3, file, flash, timer, external

I'm an Universitystudent, and I make a work in as3, my knowledge is very poor in as3...

My application, is about timers, how can I save the times to an external file? What file can I save to?

I have a doll, and a timer, and a finish line, the doll must run in the path, and the timer is counting, when the doll, pass the finish line, the counter stop, and the time that the doll have made, must be save in an external file, i don't know how to do this.

I have this code for the timer

```
var timeDisplay:TextField=new TextField();
var startTime:int = getTimer();

addChild(timeDisplay);
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, showClock);

function showClock(event:Event):void{
var timePassed:int = getTimer()-startTime;

var seconds:int = Math.floor(timePassed/1000);
var minutes:int = Math.floor(seconds/60);
seconds -= minutes*60;

var timeString:String = minutes + ":" + String(seconds+100).substr(1,2);
timeDisplay.text = timeString;
}
```

and this for the doll run

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,pressionou);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,largou);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,actualiza);

var vx:Number=0.0;

function actualiza(e:Event){
 ken.x+=vx;
}

function pressionou(e:KeyboardEvent){
  //   a65;  d68; 



if(e.keyCode==68){
    ken.gotoAndStop("run");
    vx=6;
    }

  }
function largou(e:KeyboardEvent){
    ken.gotoAndStop("stance");
    vx=0;
```

Comment: You'll need to provide us with what code you've written so far: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask we can't do all the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to call something that can write to your file. The following is a static function that will write to a file.  You may need to adjust the logic if you need to append to the file and/or use a different path.

```
public static function saveFile(filename:String, data:String):void{
  var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory;
  file = file.resolvePath(filename);
  var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
  fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
  fileStream.writeUTFBytes(data);
  fileStream.close();
}
```

The options for which directory to store in are (from [AS3 File API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html)):

- File.**applicationStorageDirectory** — a storage directory unique to each installed AIR application
- File.**applicationDirectory** — the read-only directory where the application is installed (along with any installed assets)
- File.**desktopDirectory** — the user's desktop directory
- File.**documentsDirectory** — the user's documents directory
- File.**userDirectory** — the user directory